# SubscribeAndConvert with flowcontrol

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to flow control the messages when pulling the messages using `pubSubTemplate.subscribeAndConvert`.

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and pulling the messages

```
private <T> void subscribeAndAck(String subscriptionId, Consumer<T> processor, Class<T> messageType) {
        pubSubTemplate.subscribeAndConvert(subscriptionId, message -> {
            try {
                log.info("Received message {} {}", subscriptionId, message.getPayload());
                processor.accept(message.getPayload());
                message.ack();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error("Failed processing from subscriptionId {} payload {}", subscriptionId, message.getPayload(), e);
                message.nack();
               }
        }, messageType);
    }
```

By default the flowControl is 1000 messages which is very high for my application. So I have added

```
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.flow-control.max-outstanding-element-count=10
```

But when the application starts it subscribes but throws this exception

```
2023-06-22T11:27:38.409Z ERROR 7 --- [-worker-ELG-1-1] io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl      : [Channel<11>: (pubsub.googleapis.com:443)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic!

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@7f8c8292[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@11f058e4[Wrapped task = io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$5@3014d032]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@9bc0fb5[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2065) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:833) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2065) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:833) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:562) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:705) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport.reprocess(DelayedClientTransport.java:297) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.updateSubchannelPicker(ManagedChannelImpl.java:831) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.access$4400(ManagedChannelImpl.java:105) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:562) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:705) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport.reprocess(DelayedClientTransport.java:297) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl$1UpdateBalancingState.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1146) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95) ~[grpc-api-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127) ~[grpc-api-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$TransportListener.transportReady(InternalSubchannel.java:546) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.updateSubchannelPicker(ManagedChannelImpl.java:831) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.access$4400(ManagedChannelImpl.java:105) ~[grpc-core-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ClientTransportLifecycleManager.notifyReady(ClientTransportLifecycleManager.java:43) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler$FrameListener.onSettingsRead(NettyClientHandler.java:854) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onSettingsRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:479) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onSettingsRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:702) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onSettingsRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:93) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readSettingsFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:542) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:263) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:174) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:378) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:242) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:438) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1486) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1282) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.30.2.jar!/:1.30.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I want to control the flow of the messages using subscribeAndConvert.

Comment: Fixed this - We should add 
`spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.flow-control.max-outstanding-request-bytes: 50000000`
property as well.